# Good resources to learn about MSBuild and Continuous integration with TFS

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I am relatively new to MSBuild and am looking out for good resources to learn more about MSBuild and CI with TFS.  Specifically I am looking out for the following specific tasks

- Take latest from TFS whenever a checkin happens
- Build the solution
- Run the code analysis
- Run Unit test cases
- On success deploy the project to the drop location
- Label the build

I am not looking for any reference to any books.  Online resources will be good.  I did google for this, but was not able to get and end-to-end tasks for this.

Any pointers in this direction will be appreciated.

Edit:
Also some good resources to custom MSBuild task will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is where I first started.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx)

#### Edit

I don't mean to be flippant but MSDN really is a good starting place for MSBuild and most things .NET related.

Comment: The link you provided is really a good start.  I'll watch this if any one has any quick links to the specific tasks/script I have outlined.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, everything that you describe is part of the standard TFS Build process. At least if you use MSTest for unit testing. Integration with other unit testing frameworks is also possible.

A good starting point would be MSDN, as it is quite exhaustive:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252495.aspx

TFS2008 is very pleasant to work with in regard to Team Builds. The builds can be set up through Visual Studio itself. It was a different and a lot uglier story in TFS2005 :)

You can find a lot resources on the web if you hit any obstacles during the setup. A lot of people are using it and I never had any troubles finding blog/forum posts discussing even the most obscure issues.